# How to write own metaclass?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, metaclass

How to create a metaclass in python? I tried to write as in tutorials:

```
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs2 = {'field2': 'Test'}
        attrs2.update(attrs)
        return super(Meta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs2)


class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    field1 = 10


test = Test()

print(test.field1)
print(test.field2)
```

But this code fails with error:

```
10                                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>                                                                                                                                             
    print(test.field2)                                                                                                                                                             
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'field2'
```

How to declare a metaclass in python 3.7+ correctly?

**UPDATED**
I've changed my question with actual error.

Comment: Which tutorial is this code from?

Comment: @kaya3 noone, it's my code but based on tutorials

Comment: Well, can you show us which tutorial it's based on?

Comment: @kaya3, yes, [on this](https://proglib.io/p/metaclasses-in-python/). But it's in Russian, unfortunately.

Comment: @kaya3, the tutorial is not important for me. I just want to get how to write a simple metaclass where I be able to add a new field to my class (that uses my metaclass).

Comment: Sure, but if there's working code from the tutorial, that might help people figure out the difference between that and your code.

Comment: @kaya3 it sounds logically, thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorials you are checking are covering Python 2.

In Python 3, one of the syntactic changes was exactly the way of declaring a metaclass for a class.
You don't need to change the metaclass code, just change your class declaration to:

```py
class Test(metaclass=Meta):

    field1 = 10
```

and it will work.

So, in short: for a metaclass in Python 3, you have to pass the equivalent of a "keyword argument" in the class declaration, with the name "metaclass". (Also, in Python 3, there is no need to inherit explicitly from object)

In Python 2, this was accomplished by the presence of the special variable `__metaclass__` in the body of the class, as is in your example. (Also, when setting a metaclass, inheriting from 'object' would be optional, since the metaclass, derived from type, would do that for you).

One of the main advantages of the new syntax is that it allows the special method `__prepare__` in the metaclass which can return a custom namespace object to be used when building the class body itself. It is seldom used, and a really "serious" use case would be hard to put up today. For toys and playing around, it is great, allowing for "magic autonamed enumerations" and other things - but when designing Python 3, this was way they thought to allow having an `OrderedDict` as the class namespace, so that the metaclass' `__new__` and `__init__` methods could know the order of the declaration of the attributes. Since Python 3.6, a class body namespace is ordered by default and there is no need for a `__prepare__` method for this use alone.